# What is the rule of 'of' in front a possessive pronoun?

Tags: possessives, possessive-pronouns

I'd like to know why sometimes we use 'of' in front of the possessive pronoun and sometimes we dont, like in these questions:

"Is this pen hers or yours?"

"Where is that restaurant of yours?"

Comment: I don't know how to "explain" any "rule" involved here, but I think *the presence of an **article*** may be relevant. It may be a little awkward, but syntactically there's nothing wrong with *Is this **a** pen **of** hers or [**of**] yours?* Which would be even *more* awkward with the definite article ***the*** instead of ***a***, but I'd still say it's syntactically "valid" - so maybe I should accept ***of*** with ***this*** or ***that*** as well, but I *really* don't like those versions.

Comment: (Might it just be that plain ***yours*** is a "noun", whereas ***of yours*** is a "determiner"?)

Comment: Note that *Where is that restaurant yours?* is still fine—although it means something quite different from *Where is that restaurant **of** yours?* Similarly,  *of* could be added to the first sentence. It would be less usual, but it would also change the meaning of the sentence in a converse manner.

Comment: "That restaurant of yours" implies "the one you have been talking about". Similarly, "I've found that pen of yours" would probably refer to one that 'you' had been searching for.